# Compare user input with integer

Tags: java

I'm making a program where it asks the user a simple math question and it has to tell them whether they are correct or incorrect. I'm getting errors

```
package exercises;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercises {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String number;
        System.out.println("Consider the following equation: 5x - 10");
        System.out.println("Solve for x.")
        number = user_input.next();

        if (number == 2);{
            System.out.println("Correct.");

        }else{
            System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer is 2.");
        }

}
```

Comment: `if (number == 2);{` literally everything about this statement is wrong. `number` is a String, should not be compared using `==` and cannot be compared to an `int` - or `number` should be an `int` to begin with. And drop the `;`.

Comment: Need to drop the semi colon, but error is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Please always include the error message instead of just saying "it doesn't work". What did you expect and what did actually happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two major problems and one minor.

---

### Semicolon in if

First one is the semicolon right after the if-statement. The semicolon finishes the if-statement, it is short for the if-statement without curly braces, like:

```
if (a > b) doMethod();
```

By omitting an expression and only writing the semicolon you represent a valid **NOP** (no operation), so

```
if (a > b) ;
```

is valid statement which basically does nothing.

You probably intended

```
if (number == 2) {
    System.out.println("Correct.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer is 2.");
}
```

---

### Comparison

The other problem is that your `number` variable is a `String` but you compare it with an `int`. That won't work, the result will always be `false`. You will need to convert either the `String` to `int` or vice versa for the comparison to work.

Note that comparing `String` with `String` using `==` does not work as you might expect (see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)) for details, use `String#equals` instead.

So one possibility would be `String` with `String`:

```
String number = user_input.next();

if (number.equals("2")) {
```

The other is `int` with `int`:

```
String number = user_input.next();
int asValue = Integer.parseInt(number);

if (asValue == 2) {
```

or directly use `Scanner#nextInt`:

```
int number = user_input.nextInt();

if (number == 2) {
```

---

### Missing semicolon

The minor problem is that you forgot a semicolon after the following statement

```
System.out.println("Solve for x.") // Semicolon needed
```

In Java every expression must end with a semicolon, it is a strict language.

Answer (score 0):

You have two syntax errors and both are related to semicolon `;`.

The first error is this line `System.out.println("Solve for x.")`. 
In Java every statement must end with `;`. This line has to be `System.out.println("Solve for x.");`.

The second error is in if statement: `if (number == 2);{`. You should remove semicolon after close parentheses. The correct line of code is `if (number == 2) {`.

Answer (score -3):

You are trying to compare `number` which is a String, with an integer and it can't be done, here you have two option

> 1) read an integer from `System.in`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String number;
        System.out.println("Consider the following equation: 5x - 10");
        System.out.println("Solve for x.");
        number = user_input.next();

        if (Integer.parseInt(number) == 2) {
            System.out.println("Correct.");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer is 2.");
        }
    }
```

> 2) parse the `number` as integer before comparing it with the int

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        System.out.println("Consider the following equation: 5x - 10");
        System.out.println("Solve for x.");
        number = user_input.nextInt();

        if (number == 2) {
            System.out.println("Correct.");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer is 2.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should offer some explanation. Otherwise it provides little help.

Comment: While that code works, you will need to explain the changes. Otherwise it won't help OP that much.

Comment: Just use `nextInt()`